# why it doesnt accept a concated string as parameter in SP?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I wrote an SP that works perfectly. I was calling the SP with regular parameters and worked. However, now I need to call the SP like below

```
EXEC @v_nReturn = sp_get_next_value 'LP_' + @WhID + '_COUNTER'
```

The intellisense gives an error on the first `'+'` sign.

> It says "incorrect syntax err...."

`@WhID` is `NVARCHAR(10)`, so I shouldn't convert it to `NVARCHAR`.

what is the problem?

Comment: unfortunately you cannot concatenate and create a string while passing it as a parameter to a procedure , use a variable, set it by concatenating the string and then pass the variable to the procedure

Comment: I just tried it and It worked. Please post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't do (full) expression parsing when you call a stored procedure.  This is definitely an area where a small change would be highly convenient, although there are probably good reasons for the limitation.

As mentioned in a comment, use a separate variable:

```
DECLARE @arg varchar(256) =  'LP_' + @WhID + '_COUNTER';
EXEC @v_nReturn = sp_get_next_value @arg;
```

Be careful if `@WhID` is numeric.  Then you need to convert the value to a string first.

Comment: I don't know the code in the stored procedure. But I want to warn that unchecked string concatenation and passing that as a parameter is a possible door for **SQL Injection**.

Answer (score 1):

Try with parens:

```
EXEC @v_nReturn = (sp_get_next_value 'LP_' + @WhID + '_COUNTER')
```